# iPhone stops playing audio in the background

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, background

Our iPhone app is configured to play audio in the background, and most of the time it works well and the audio is playing.
But we had several reports from users that while the app is in the background and it IS playing audio, suddenly in the middle of playback it stops.
It seems to happen usually when the user is using apps like Facebook or WhatsApp heavily, sending and receiving many messages.
When the user returns to the app, it seems to start from the launch screen, as if it was closed, not just the audio stopped.
There seems to be no crash logs on the users phones when this happens.

What can cause this? What can we do to prevent this or what can we do to investigate when this happens? Can it be prevented entirely?

Answer (score 0):

apple fixed this already.

Before the release of iOS 10.0.2, the only way to fix the bug was to unplug the EarPods and then plug them back in. Not all devices were affected, but it looks like Apple finally found the fix it promised earlier this week.

Here is an article: http://www.cultofmac.com/446417/apple-fixes-iphone-audio-issues-ios-update/

Comment: this doesn't seem to be related to the issue I am having. My app is terminated while in the background, it's not just stop playing sound from the headphones.